# How to reveal hidden paragraph with each click in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a 5 paragraphs that i want to reveal one by one with each click. I think that they must be hidden (
        `visibility: hidden`) and reveals one by one with jQuery .show().

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

:hidden selector selects all hidden elements and :first selects first of those

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $(":hidden:first").show();
});
```

alternatively, if u want to show a particular paragraph, you can be more specific e.g.:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $( /parent/ ).find("p:hidden:first").show();
});
```